# How do I call a .Net dll (function) from Java on mono/linux

Tags: java, c#, linux, jni4net

As the subject says, is this possible? I know of jni4net but its on windows.

Heres an excerpt of the error I get:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/mydll.dll which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Native code library failed to load.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to create a function in C that is called from the Java code, and that calls your C# function in return.

Have a look [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/) for the C to C# bridge.

Answer (score 0):

JNBridgePro supports your scenario.  It supports running the .NET side on Mono, so the .NET side can run on Linux. See the JNBridge website for more information.

Disclosure: I am with JNBridge.